# I've got issues with my php code

Tags: php, pdo

First, I want to give the codes;

```
 public function productPrice($id) {
            $productPrice = $this->db1->query("SELECT price FROM oc_product WHERE product_id='{$id}'");
            $productPrice = $productPrice->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
            foreach ($productPrice as $a) {
                $productOnSale = $this->db1->query("SELECT price FROM oc_product_special WHERE product_id='{$a}'");
                $productOnSale = $productOnSale->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
                if (is_array($productOnSale) || is_object($productOnSale)) {
                    foreach ($productOnSale as $b) {
                    if ($a == $b) {
                        $a = explode(".", $a);
                        return $a[0] . " TL";
                    } else {
                        $a = explode(".", $a);
                        $b = explode(".", $b);
                        return "<strike>".$a[0]." TL</strike>\n".$b[0]." TL";

                    }
                }
            }
            }
        }
```

Everything is fine when i'm fetching `else`
But it doesn't give me `if` even $a and $b values are correct.
And the error line is: foreach ($productOnSale as $b) {

And if don't use `if (is_array($productOnSale) || is_object($productOnSale))` statement, it gives me Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 38: foreach ($productOnSale as $b)

Comment: there should be product ID instead of product price in the second query

Comment: what is the error occure

Comment: @asfandahmed1 funny thing is, $a and $id gives me same result. It's not problem with that, if it was the problem, it wouldn't give me 'else'

Comment: $productOnSale->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM); try this

Comment: But i'm fetching one value, fetchAll won't work, i tried it also

Answer (score 0):

in second query change **WHERE product_id** to **WHERE product_price**